# Jquery remove script bad coding

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is a good way to write this script more dynamic:

I have a variable which can have a value up to 18.

If $count is 1 I want to remove everything up to 18.

If $count is 2 I want to remove everything up to 18.

And so on.

```
        if($count == 1) {
            $('#input-1').remove();
            // remove up to 18
        }
        if($count == 2) {
            $('#input-2').remove();
            // remove up to 18
        }
        if($count == 3) {
            $('#input-3').remove();
            // remove up to 18
        }
        ...
        if($count == 18) {
            $('#input-18').remove();
        }
```

I did this:

```
            for(var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
                if($count== i) {
                    $('#input-'+i).remove();
                }
            }
```

but it does not remove the divs from i to 18

**EDIT: (to be clear)**

I want to check each, like `$count == i` then I want to remove from i to 18

Comment: Use a loop: `for (var i = $count; i <= 18; i++) { ... }`

Comment: Your question is a bit odd. Can you please add the `HTML` too?

Comment: Could use more information regarding this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
for(var i = $count; i <= 18;i++){
   $('#input-'+i).remove();
}
```

**EDIT**

> I want to check each, like $count == i then I want to remove from i to
>   18

The outer `for loop` allows us to check if `i` is equal to `$count`, if the expression is satisfied (`true`) then we simply begin another loop starting at `i`. Within the second `for loop`, we begin removing the elements from `i` and beyond.

```
for(var i = 1; i <=18; i++) {
    if($count == i) {
       for(var j = i; j <= 18; j++){
         $('#input-'+j).remove();
       }
      return;
    }
}
```

**Note** - This will send a return value of undefined to the caller. However, you can specify a different return value if you wish to.

Comment: but I want to  check each like $count == i then remove from i to 18

Comment: @J.Alan okay i will do another solution for that if you like.

Comment: @J.Alan just do me a favour and update your question with the comment you've just written --> " 
but I want to check each like $count == i then remove from i to 18"

Comment: Seems to work so far I will test it again after a few hours then I am going to tick your answer :D

Comment: Could you explain the the nested for loop so I can understand it better please:)

Comment: @J.Alan i will update my answer  with the explanation :).

Comment: @J.Alan check for update, if you need anything else, I will create a chat room for us two rather then carry on on chatting here. :).

Comment: Thanks alot everything is clear to me now, have a nice week!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this `$("#input-"+$count).remove()`

Comment: Based upon OP's stated intention - this makes the most sense.

Comment: Okay - now the question was edited - this no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.!

```
for (var i = $count; i <= 18; i++) {
  $('#input-' + i).remove();
}
```

Comment: but I want to  check each like $count == i then remove from i to 18

Comment: @Andreas noted. Thanks.. (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop

```
for(let i=$count;i<=18;i++){
    $('#input-'+i).remove();
}
```

This will iterate starting from `$count` to `18` and will remove all input with id between `$count` and `18`

Comment: but I want to  check each like $count == i then remove from i to 18

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be a loop with a variable using [Template-Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```js
const addElements = function() {
  // Add elements dynamically
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const div = `<div id="element-${i}">I\'m ${i}</div>`;
    $('body').append(div);
  }
}

const removeElements = function() {
  // Remove elements dynamically
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const $div = $(`div#element-${i}`);

    $div.remove();
  }
}


$('#addBtn').on('click', function() {
  addElements();
});

$('#removeBtn').on('click', function() {
  removeElements();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="removeBtn">Remove</button>
<button id="addBtn">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
var start=$('input-'+$count);
var end=$('#input-18').index();
$('input').slice(start,end).remove();
```

If the only inputs you have are `$('input-1)` to `$('#input-18')`, you can skip the check and do:

```
  $('input').slice($count-1).remove();
```